# Autowired Domain/Entity classes retains Old values

Tags: spring, java-8

I have a mapper class for an incoming Event message.

Once the event message comes to the application, the mapper class sets the values in the entity object and saves it in the Database.
I have Autowired the entity object in my mapper class.

Whenever a new event comes in, the autowired entity object is still having the Old/previous values.

Is autowiring of Domain/Entity object possible in this case or I should go with 'New' keyword instead of Autowiring as Spring bean.

I see some posts about using @Configurable. I am not sure which is the best coding practice in this case?

```
@Service
public class LegacyEventMapper {

        @Autowired
        private LegacyEvent legacyEvent;

        @Autowired
        private LegacyEntity legacyEntity;

        public void mapLegacyNotificationDetails(LegacyScheduleEvent body) throws Exception {
       //Setting the values into the Entity object
```

Thanks

Comment: Please attach the code where you autowire and the mapper

Comment: added the code now

Comment: @firstpostcommenter you are autowiring an entity, your `LegacyEntity` is actually annotated with `@Entity`?

Comment: Yes, the entity class is autowired with @Entity annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you actually want to `@Autowire` an `@Entity` and make it spring aware. This is wrong. You *can* do it, but it makes absolutely no sense.

What you actually want to do is create a new LegacyEntity (via the `new LegacyEntity`) and save that instance to DB.

What you have read via `@Configurable` is the other way around - you inject a spring bean/service into an Entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think We can `@Autowire` an `@Entity` class. But then we need to mention in Entity class that it is of Request scope

```
@Entity
@Scope(scopeName=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class LegacyEntity {
```

I am not sure if using the `new` keyword is the better approach instead of autowiring an Entity class?